# how to test error files in uppy uploader?

Tags: uploader, uppy

I tried to check an error uploading to aws3. The only manipulation I success to check is after I dropped the files, to change the name of one of them.There are another options to check uploading error files?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean after the the aws uploader tried to upload the file, then use the .on("upload-error") function.

```
.on('upload-error', (error) => {
    console.log(error);
  })
```